# Django - variable in view

Tags: django

I'm new to Django so this may seem obvious but I haven't been able to figure this one out.  I have a view that needs an IP address to perform various actions.  It works fine when I specify the IP address manually in the view like this:

```
node = '127.0.0.1'
```

I have the IP addresses stored in a model, so my question is how would I set the "node" variable in the view using data from the model in conjunction with a captured value from the url?

Edit - here is the model currently, let me know if it should be done differently.

```
   class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ip = models.IPAddressField('IP Address')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

So "name" would be the captured value in the url and then it would find "ip" using the captured value.  Of course if there is a better way to do it please let me know.

Comment: How are the models, and the view you have created defined ? and what do you mean by `data in the model in conjunction with`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do something along the lines of a page that shows info for a server, including IP (presumably, if you can do this, you can use the ip to do whatever you ACTUALLY want to do).

Similar to peter's answer, you'd have a URL that looks like

```
url(r'^server_info/(?P<server_name>\w+)/$', 'server_info_view', name='server_info'),
```

the in the view

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def server_info_view(request, server_name):
    server = get_object_or_404(Server, name=server_name)
    node = server.ip
    # Keep in mind, at this point 'node' is a django.models.IPAddressField object, you might need
    node = str(node)
    # Which should get you an IP in the format you have above, though I'm not sure.
```

Answer (score 0):

Put some kind of identifier in the URL (I usually just use the PK of the model), fetch the object, and do whatever you need with it.

Something like this:

In urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^item_detail/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', 'my_viewname', name='my_item_detail'),
...
```

For the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def my_viewname(request, item_id):
    my_item = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=int(item_id))
    node = my_item.node
    ...
```

If you're using class-based generic views, `DetailView` or anything that inherits from SingleObjectMixin can do this using the `slug_url_kwarg` or `pk_url_kwarg` settings.